# How we can reverse and remove the same message with to different buttons with VueJS?

Tags: html, vue.js

For this exercise I try for the same message to inverse it and to remove it with two different buttons. I code something this the VueJS tutorial, but I have a problem, the console tell me:

> this.text is not a function

I tried many things, and lean many thing too but I don't understand why this kind of code doesn't work.
Can you help me please?

This my HTML code :

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="newTodo" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <span>{{ todo.text }}</span>
      <button v-on:click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
      <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is my VueJS code :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newTodo: '',
    todos: [
      { text: 'Add some todos' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function (index) {
      this.text = this.text.split('').reverse({ text: text }).join('');
    },

    addTodo: function () {
      var text = this.newTodo.trim();
      if (text) {
        this.todos.push({ text: text });
        this.newTodo = '';
      }
    },

    removeTodo: function (index) {
      this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If you use the old way for a function declaration the function will have a `this` of its own which might not be the `this` you expect. You can fix that by adding `.bind(this)` after the end of your function body (like `}.bind(this);`).

Answer (score 0):

First you can add the index argument ([doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for)) for the `v-for` loop to find the current todo to remove.

For `reverseMessage`, just pass the todo as argument and reverse its `text` property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    newTodo: '',
    todos: [
      { text: 'Add some todos' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo() {
      let text = this.newTodo.trim();
      if (text) {
        let todo = { text: text }
        this.todos.push(this.reverseMessage(todo))
        this.newTodo = ''
      }
    },
    reverseMessage(todo) {
      todo.text = todo.text.split('').reverse().join('')
      return todo
    },
    removeTodo(i) {
      this.todos.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="newTodo" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(todo, i) in todos">
      <span>{{ todo.text }}</span>
      <button v-on:click="removeTodo(i)">X</button>
      <button v-on:click="reverseMessage(todo)">Reverse Message</button>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: but I need to do this for other message I add with "v-model" but here we reverse just the first 'add some todos'. Sorry I forgot to precise this thing

Comment: @Truffier-BlancSh but 'Add some todos' is a todo in your example. If you add more you can see each can be reverse or remove independently. It's not what you're looking for ?

Comment: yes it is exactly what I looking for but when I try on my VisualStudio and I open my HTML file in the browser I can remover other message, just 'Add some todos' with your code

Comment: if "Add some todos" is just a title, remove it from your `todos` array and make it a proper title or even a placeholder for the input.

Comment: sorry I don't really understand what do you mean

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood your comment here *"I can remover other message, just 'Add some todos' with your code"*. I thought you wanted to keep "Add some todos" as a title. Anyway i don't know why it's not working with your IDE, it works fine here if you run the snippet.

Comment: in fact what I meant: each new message entered in the v-model will appear below the "add some todos", and I would like these messages entered by the user to be also reverse

Comment: @Truffier-BlancSh you want a todo to be reversed on click button **and** when you add it on first time ?

Comment: yes I want a todo to be reversed and each I added something with the v-model

Comment: sorry but can you help me again with this kind of problem?

Comment: @ShirleyTruffier-Blanc i updated my answer. Run the snippet and tell me if it's what you expect.

Comment: no sorry it is not what I expect, or It doesn't work with me. I expect when I add something with the v-model I want to reverse this thing too, for example if It wrote "hello" in the box and I press enter I have hello under 'add some todos' and I want to reverse hello too